# Battery discharging

Tags: batteries, discharge

What will happen if I keep using the non-rechargeable battery below its nominal voltage?

This question comes in my mind when I am working on a circuit which can also work below the nominal voltage of my battery.

Can just use the battery until my circuit stops working?
I am using two 1.5V battery in series.

Comment: *So, why not I can just use the battery until my circuit stops working.* Who says that cannot be done? Do you measure the voltage in your TV's remote regularly and change them before it stops working or do you just replace them when the remote actually does stop working?

Comment: It kind of depends on the failure mode of under-power condition. If your application is fail-safe or could fail gracefully, then it's OK. But for some applications, like a computer or a smart phone, the under-power failure isn't very "clean" or "graceful": there is a period of time when the device is not properly functional but not fully incapacitated, either. In a lot of cases the capacitor in the internal power supply can keep the system up in that state for dozens of milliseconds and that's enough time for a rogue processor to do some serious damage.

Comment: What you describe is exactly  what a Joule Thief does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your question "What will happen...":  Answer  is "something bad or nothing bad".  It depends what you are powering with your non-rechargeable battery, just as the three comments Which you already have are telling you.

The question "Can I ... use the battery until...".  Answer is yes, but the responsibility is entirely yours if there is a resultant software mess to "clean up" afterwards (again ref. the three comments extant at this juncture).

So you "work on circuits..." which you drive with your battery.

And so to my real answers...
Answer #1: Only use this battery supply to work on circuits which won't scramble with a slow fade of the power supply (so there is no software "mess" to "clean up" in the circuit when you get new batteries).

Answer #2: Pragmatism (one of my favourite words!) would dictate putting a large electrolytic capacitor ("how large" is like asking "how long is a piece of string?", but go with 1,000uF minimum) in parallel with the battery.  This would effectively combat some of the deleterious effects of a rising battery ESR as it fades. ie. for practical purposes, the battery life is extended a little for circuits which require brief surges of higher current from a slowly dying battery.

Answer #3: Use of a 3V battery and your concern about the voltage fading/battery life implies that you are using batteries to guarantee a pure DC with no ripple at all and that you you probably need this pure DC to work on delicate digital, partially dismantled sub-assemblies.

I could be very wrong with that assumption, but please let me "run with it" because it is my primary reason for the nature of advice I give you below.

Given all that, there will certainly be times when the digital circuits you are working on will be software-sensitive, so use the electrolytic I suggest in my answer #2 *AND* monitor your battery volts *AND* don't go below 3V.  If you are using carbon-zinc cells, then be assured that when your battery voltage is exactly 3V, then you will have had quite a lot of good use from it as it has faded from its initial 3.3-3.5V full charge status.  If you are using alkalines, I can't speak about terminal voltages at various degrees of discharge, but by their nature you will have had much longer useage from an alkaline battery before it goes significantly under 3V exactly.

And nothing to do with your question, but if you are indeed working on dismantled CMOS digital sub-assemblies which can be very vulnerable to "stray" electricity, please do it in a static-safe workplace.  It could be that a dying battery may be the least of your worries if there is the risk of static spikes helping to ruin what you are trying to repair or program.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I am using the battery for microcontroller and OP-amp. As you mention the dying battery may generate the spike which will enough to blow my controller actually. Anyways now I am using a rechargeable battery which will cost less to me.

Comment: a dying battery generating a spike isn't what I & user 3528438 meant. Apologies if confusion in my wording. What MAY happen with some software-sensitive devices is devices a little under the minimum operating voltage may screw up possible programming in your devices (depending on device). This may mean reformat of the device program if slightly low battery volts screwed it up, but not a hardware repair. Big electro across battery not for spike suppression, it's (comparatively) low ESR can keep voltage above minimum when your devices need a surge of current AND battery is close to minimum

Comment: Me having added that last comment, you might find it interesting to research if you still need my suggested large electrolytic across any rechargeable battery, because it's highly likely that any rechargeable you bought recently will maintain a low ESR until battery volts overall have dropped below device spec. ie. I'm saying more likely your new battery just above minimum EMF is less likely to briefly drop below voltage spec with any brief current surges required by  controller or a DUT. But Care! A Ni-Cd or Ni-MH can lose much EMF suddenly, w little advance warning. Good batts. tho'

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I understood your point of spikes now. I am using a Li-ion battery. Added an electrolyte capacitor for fast transient response and a ceramic one for low ESR between battery positive and ground. I think it solves the problem of ESR when battery starts dying.

Answer (score 0):

As the voltage of a primary cell decreases, its internal resistance increases. This reduces the cell's maximum current output. If the cell is no longer able to provide enough current to the device then the device will not function properly (exact details of "not function properly" depend on the device and how it was designed) even though the cell may have plenty of stored energy left.